# Image rating aplication problems in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem with the picture rating application that I am working on. I don’t regularly program with C#, so if anyone could help, that would be the best thing that has happened so far to me!!

I am programming in visual studio 2008, the base for the application is made in Microsoft Access.

So what I am trying to do:

I have made a table in Access and I am trying to get some information out of it. The table name is dogodek and it consists of id_dogodek, id_category, title, author, ratings and picture (just URL-s). 
So I can fill the table in my application, but I have a problem, how to present the picture with the highest rating. I don’t know how to load the information’s from the base and then use it.

This is what I have done!

```
private void images()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT id_dogodek,picture,MAX(ratings) FROM 'dogodek'"; //it do not work


    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    //How to load the image to (Image1)??
    Image1.ImageUrl = "images/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fotografija"].ToString();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: "how to present the picture with the highest rating" do you mean something other than a simple 
ORDER BY ratings DESC" ??

Comment: Babak's right, although it's not clear what the column type for 'ratings' is - for now, i'm assuming it's indeed a scalar numeric type (int or whatever), and since you don't seem to be using the other columns, you could just make the sql into 'select picture from dogodek order by ratings desc" and then (AFAICT) change the column index from fotografija to picture

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 id_dogodek,picture,ratings
FROM 'dogodek'
ORDER BY ratings DESC
```

MAX(ratings) is only for when you're grouping (GROUP BY), ie if there's another table that has lots of ratings for each id_dogodek.

Comment: does 'top 1' work in Access?  It might - for some reason I thought it was specific to SQL Server so I left that out as part of my comment.

Comment: Yep, TOP X is in it. In the GUI query designer it's represented by a "return:" box in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY ratings DESC) AS 'Order' , id_dogodek,picture,ratings
   FROM dogodek
) D
WHERE [Order] =1
```